# New file won't integrate in Magento with getchild()

Tags: magento

I want to make a new pop-up and I want to copy an existing login-form modal for it.

So I have done the following things:

1) create the new modal file `shipping.modal.phtml` and save it under `app/design/frontend/sm-maxshop/default/template/checkout`

2) the new modal should work for the `cart.phtml`, so i have add the following code into the `cart.phtml` from the folder `app/design/frontend/sm-maxshop/default/template/checkout` -

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('checkout_shipping_modal'); ?>
```

3) I have edited the `page.xml` (because the new modal will work for different sites) in this way

```
<block type="checkout/template" name="checkout_shipping_modal" after="-" template="checkout/shipping.modal.phtml" />
```

I think now it should work, but the code of the new "shipping.modal.html" is not included in the page.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue With block type..
can you give more detail what is in shipping.modal.phtml file